# WP7: Conditionally show & hide control elements in Data Templates

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, silverlight-3.0

I have a note application with a ListBox control, which lists all the available notes from the `ObservableCollection<Note> Notes`. `class Note` has attributes like

```
String Title;
bool Has_Reminder;
DateTime Reminder_Date;
```

What I want is that the TextBlock element, which shows the `Reminder_Date`, is only shown, if `Has_Reminder` is true. But I do not know how to access this attribute from my custom control NoteListItem. Its `this.DataContext` attribute is `null`, but the control still properly displays the Note's bound attributes handed down by the ListBox ItemsSource. How can I achieve that?

Thanks for your help.

**I tried to read the attributes in the constructor, which did not work:**

```
public NoteListItem()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Note this_note = LayoutRoot.DataContext as Note; // turns out, this_note is null

    if (!this_note.Has_Reminder)
        Reminder_Info.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

**NoteListItem control**

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" >
    <TextBlock x:Name="Title" Text="{Binding Title}" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="Reminder_Date" Text="{Binding Reminder_Date}" />
</Grid>
```

**NoteList control:**

```
<ListBox x:Name="NoteListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Notes}" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:NoteListItem />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you know how to use a converter? Your converter would convert a bool to a Visibility, then you can bind the TextBlock's Visibility to `Has_Reminder`:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="Reminder_Date" Text="{Binding Reminder_Date}" Visibility="{Binding Has_Reminder, Converter={...}}"/>
```

This might help: http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2008/07/visibility-type-converter/

Comment: Finally had the time to check out your source. Wow, that was simple! Before this I had no idea how to use a converter. Thanks for that guide!