# Text box decision making, C# - Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

How to apply "if conditions" on textBoxs?

Like I want to develop "GPA Calculator" application.
When application starts, I want to ask a user **Number of Subjects**, so that only that **number of textBoxes & Labels will appear that user wants.**

Does "decision making" used in XAML Coding?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463759/wp7-conditionally-show-hide-control-elements-in-data-templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most probably want to use a `ListBox` with its elements (your text boxes and labels in needed amount) are tied to the view model via data-binding. I hope you're familiar with data binding in XAML & C#, but if not, check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278072%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) out.

So, I'd create a `ListBox` with the `ItemsSource` property data-bound to an instance of `ObservableCollection`, containing view models for your list view.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding GPAItems}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding GPAItemLabel}" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding GPAItemText, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

where `GPAItems` is `ObservableCollection<GPAItem>`, and `GPAItem` is:

```
class GPAItem: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...
    public string GPAItemLabel {get; set;}
    public string GPAItemText {get; set;}
}
```

The code above is not tested (I've just written it in browser for you), but you should get the idea from here. Again, knowledge of data-binding and MVVM architecture is highly beneficial for any Windows Phone developer, so check it out, and most questions will go away.

Comment: Thanks, I will try then tell you more what I discover

Answer (score 1):

Take the input of the textbox and use it to choose the number of textboxes and labels to appear. I dont think you need to use 'if'

Comment: @Khateeb  Using the input of the textbox to tell how many labels and textboxes you want